# I need to find confidence intervals on a graph i Have a dataset with 2 column confidence in police and race

Tags: r, graph

Create a barplot showing Canadians' average confidence in police by race. race should be on the x-axis, and your y-axis should show average confidence toward the police. Include confidence intervals. Make sure the x-axis and y-axis are sensibly labelled.

Can someone please help me with how to do this with the confidence intervals

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**, the **code** you tried and the **packages** you used? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) To post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.

Comment: ggplot(df, aes (x = race,y = confstd_police)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  labs(x= "Race", y = "Feelings Towards Police", title = "Average confidence in Police")

Comment: thats what ive done so far but it doesnt seem right as they are both similar when people of colour should be lower